# Exact and closed forms with a vanishing Riemann tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

I need a result to prove that an closed form is equally exact. I work under the assumption that the Riemann tensor vanishes everywhere on the manifold. (It is the context of general relativity.)

The [wikipedia-page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms) on the subject, mentions Poincaré's lemma. But I can't link the theorem, if it is indeed applicable, to the assumption: namely that the Riemann tensor vanishes.

(Please be aware that I don't have a heavy back-ground in differential geometry.)

Thanks!

Comment: I also do not know much riemannian geometry, but I would guess that the riemann tensor vanishes on the flat torus, which has nontrivial cohomology.  But that is just a guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steven makes a very pertinent point in the comments - if the implication you want is

$$\mathrm{Rm} = 0 \implies H^k (M^n) =0 $$

then the flat tori provide counterexamples - the $k$-form $ dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^k$ on the flat torus $\mathbb T^n = \mathbb R^n / \mathbb Z^n$ ($n\ge k$) is clearly closed, but it has non-zero integral over the closed chain $\mathbb T^k \subset \mathbb T^n$ and is thus not exact.